# How to start containerd as a service after yum install?

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, systemd, amazon-linux-2, containerd

I installed [containerd](https://containerd.io/) on Amazon Linux 2 using the [suggested commands](https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/614#issuecomment-559619366):

```
sudo amazon-linux-extras enable docker
sudo yum install -y containerd
```

I added this in the [EC2 user data script](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html) to run at instance launch time.

But, how am I supposed to start `containerd` (a container runtime - similar to docker) as a service? Since I installed through `yum` there doesn't seem to include a *systemd service file*. The binary is located on `/usr/bin/containerd`. Am I supposed to use `echo` in the boot script to generate a *systemd service file* or what is a good practice?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think the containerd is really designed to be used without docker or kubernetes or something else. I thought it was just the runtime component other things use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with adding these lines to the startup script:

```
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/systemd/system/containerd.service
[Unit]
Description=containerd
Documentation=https://containerd.io

[Service]
Type=notify
ExecStart=/usr/bin/containerd

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
EOF

sudo systemctl enable containerd
sudo systemctl start containerd
```

Looks like the `containerd` service was started:

```
$ sudo ctr version
Client:
  Version:  1.4.6
  Revision: d71fcd7d8303cbf684402823e425e9dd2e99285d
  Go version: go1.15.12

Server:
  Version:  1.4.6
  Revision: d71fcd7d8303cbf684402823e425e9dd2e99285d
  UUID: 25f1bff3-b72d-45f2-99d2-78c0df126faa
```